# Unable to communicate to a WCF service with this setup: IIS with a WCF service behind a Microsoft Forefront/TMG with a SSL certificate

Tags: wcf, iis, ssl-certificate, wcf-security

I have a WCF service running behind a Microsoft Forefront/TMG. The service is on a IIS using port 80. The TMG listen to port 443. The TMG has a SSL certificate installed. The TMG setup is done by our IT department. I am able to access `https://mypublicsite:443/myservice.svc` and `https://mypublicsite:443/myservice.svc?wsdl`. However if using the Visual Studio test-client: WCFTestClient.exe (or any client) - I get a timeout when doing an invocation with this error:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

I stuck right now. When accessing the service using `http://myinternalsite:80/myservice.svc` from inside the network everything works. Anyone that has a solution? Or a way to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Got [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to show the content of the network packages. And this guided me to a solution. The reasons for the 500 responses was due to WCF AddressFilter mismatch. This was fixed by adding this to my service: `[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]`

This is the article that helped me:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b5ae495b-f5fb-4eed-ae21-2b2280d4fec3/

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

- You being blocked by a firewall (try telnet)
- That there is something wrong with the TMG setup (try accessing service wsdl from browser)
- That your wcf config is set to use / not use transport security (check that the server and client config files match)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had no value for zero on a Enum sent by the service.
If using **Enums** make sure the value sent is defined. **Default is 0**.

```
[DataContract]
public enum MyEnum // No name for value 0 in this enum
{
    [EnumMember]
    Something1=1,
    [EnumMember]
    Something2=2,   
}
```